# PHP proving a challenge - natsort with <a> tags

Tags: php, natsort

The goal is to be able to gather all images from a folder, sort and then put individually into `<a>` tags to be able to rel to a lightbox gallery I have.
The problem that occurs is that when I launch the lightbox it starts on the last image in the folder. I am at a loss and cannot work out how to get it to start from the beginning of the images.. when I displayed all of them with `<img>` tags they display in the correct order with the top image being the first image in the folder.

```
$files = array(); 
$dir = "Images/Sample Album/Pack Album"; 

if ($dir_handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dir_handle)) !== FALSE) {
        if ($file!="."&&$file!="..")
            $files[] = $file;
     }
     closedir($dir_handle);
}

natsort($files); 

foreach($files as $file) { 
    echo  "<a href='$dir/$file' rel='prettyPhoto[gallery2]' "; 
}
```

Comment: did you played with asort along with natsort?

Comment: Have you tried closing the `<a>` tags?

Comment: Vlvzl - I'll have a look into it now, thanks for the pointer. Sam - basically this file is being link to from my main html page and in the html page it closes the tag there, for some reason if I closed it in this php command it would duplicate the end image..

Comment: Install firebug (or other javascript console) and look at your javascript errors.

Comment: and there is a validator for your HTML. just for the moments where mistakes happen. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense. The HTML you're outputting isn't even close to valid, you're missing the `>`. And every `<a>` needs a matching `</a>`, it's very unlikely the main page adds enough.

Comment: @GregThomas If you want to address a comment to a specific person, you have to put `@` before their name. That notifies them that someone has replied to them.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
$files = array_reverse(natsort($files));
```

Comment: could help here, but honestly, it's one of those typo questions. Users that are too dumb to verify their HTML output in the browser before asking a question here and such.

Comment: Note that `array_reverse` doesn't work by reference (like natsort does), so you actually need to save the return value somewhere.

Comment: `natsort()` doesn't return the array, it returns a boolean (documentation says it returns FALSE on failure -- how can it fail?).